# How to send back an image variable from one screen to another - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and I am currently working on a project that uses cameras internally.This screen has two image variables that need to receive an image from the camera and store them easily.
Right now the camera screen is closed like this:

`onPressed: ()=> Navigator.pop(context,Image.file(File(imagePath)))`

How do I change the Image variables from the previous screen?

Comment: use setState, or other statemanagement like getx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are passing a widget `Image.file(File(imagePath))` to result parameter of `Navigator.pop`. So in this case, the code where you open the camera screen using `Navigator.push` , you can assign the return value of `Navigator.push` to some variable because the return type is `Future<T>`.

```dart
final imgWidget = await Navigator.push<Image>(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to do that but didn't realised it need the <Image>. However, after doing that if I try to use a construtor to change the variable with the result's value it still receives a null value. How can I make sure the result isn't null? I tried using one single method to get the result and do the constructor but that didn't worked. If and else apparently don't work with async either.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has no concept of different screens. Everything is Widgets and you have a Widget tree. Between straight Provider, Riverpod, Bloc and GetX there are a variety of different state management solutions that allow you to store information over the level of pages.